# R - Warnings when creating empty data.frame w/ 21+ cols in Jupyter

Tags: r, jupyter, jupyter-irkernel

I have a funny problem, when I create an empty data.frame with 21 columns:

```
data.frame(x01 = numeric(),
           x02 = numeric(),
           x03 = numeric(),
           x04 = numeric(),
           x05 = numeric(), 
           x06 = numeric(),
           x07 = numeric(), 
           x08 = numeric(), 
           x09 = numeric(), 
           x10 = numeric(),
           x11 = numeric(), 
           x12 = numeric(),
           x13 = numeric(),
           x14 = numeric(), 
           x15 = numeric(),
           x16 = numeric(),
           x17 = numeric(),
           x18 = numeric(),
           x19 = numeric(),
           x20 = numeric(), 
           x21 = numeric())
```

I get the following three warnings:

```
Warning message in cbind(parts$left, ellip_h, parts$right, deparse.level = 0L):
“number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)”
Warning message in cbind(parts$left, ellip_h, parts$right, deparse.level = 0L):
“number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)”
Warning message in cbind(parts$left, ellip_h, parts$right, deparse.level = 0L):
“number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)”
Warning message in cbind(parts$left, ellip_h, parts$right, deparse.level = 0L):
“number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)”
```

There are no problems though, when I create a df with only 20 columns, i.e. leaving out the last one. Problem is not specific to 21 cols, with more columns I still get the warnings. Any ideas what the problem is and what to do about it?

Thanks!

edit: this only occurs in Jupyter (I'm running R version 3.6.3 on Ubuntu)

Comment: I don't get that warning message. Restart R and try again.

Comment: thanks for checking! i can also *not* replicate this in the terminal. It seems to be a Jupyter thing though (I can replicate it in both Jupyter and Jupyterhub)

Answer (score 0):

How about trying

```
> data.frame(do.ca .... [TRUNCATED]
 [1] X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X7  X8  X9  X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16 X17 X18 X19
[20] X20 X21
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Comment: thanks Thomas for checking. Despite the warning, the above does actually work. I mostly wanna understand what's going on rather than finding a way around it though